# Trick to rewrite operator in terms of another?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis

In the book Beautiful Models: 70 Years of Exactly Solved Quantum Many-Body Problems by Bill Sutherland, I would like to understand the trick done in (4), see the excerpt from p 29 shown below
[image: figure]

I don't see how (4) could boil down to (3), how have the eigenvectors been rewritten?